# decimal to binary java program

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm trying to make a java program where the user inputs a decimal number and it it then converted to binary. this is what i have so far but the while loop only loops once and only gives me 0 when i input 8. I know 8 in binary is 1000 so i don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I need the coding to be simple. please help thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class binary
 {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userNum = 0;
    int binary = 0;
    double newNum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a positive base 10 number: ");
    userNum = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    for(; (Math.pow(2,count) <= userNum); count++)
    {

    }

    while(!(count == 0))
    {
        if(userNum/Math.pow(2,count) != 0)
        {
            binary = userNum/(int)Math.pow(2,count);
            System.out.print(binary);
        }

        userNum %= Math.pow(2,count);
        count--;
        userNum %= (int)Math.pow(2,count));
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't re-invent the wheel, use [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a positive base 10 number: ");
if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    int userNum = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("%d decimal is %s binary%n", userNum,
            Integer.toBinaryString(userNum));
}
```

Also, Java classes should start with a capital letter. So your `binary` should probably be `Binary`. Finally, if you need to convert from binary to decimal, you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String, 2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: It's a useful function, but it's always good to know how things work under the hood -- in this case how base conversion works.

Comment: @jackarms At the very least, this is valuable for verifying the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic like below:

```
package com.java2novice.algos;

public class DecimalToBinary {

public void printBinaryFormat(int number){
    int binary[] = new int[25];
    int index = 0;
    while(number > 0){
        binary[index++] = number%2;
        number = number/2;
    }
    for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){
        System.out.print(binary[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    DecimalToBinary dtb = new DecimalToBinary();
    dtb.printBinaryFormat(25);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just got :

```
for(userNum = userNum; (Math.pow(2,count) <= userNum); count++)
{

}
```

Instead of:

```
for(userNum = userNum; (Math.pow(2,count) <= userNum); count++){
while(!(count == 0))
{
    if(userNum/Math.pow(2,count) != 0)
    {
        binary = userNum/(int)Math.pow(2,count);
        System.out.print(binary);
    }

    newNum = userNum%Math.pow(2,count);
    count--;
    userNum = (int)(newNum%(int)Math.pow(2,count));
}}
}
}
```

Basically you got empty if.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues:

Your `count` is going to always start one too high, since the last part of the `for` loop is going to be to increment it again.

You need the `while` loop to run when `count` is 0 to check the last bit.

The rest looks like it should be good, but I don't understand what the statements mean with `newNum`.

An easier version of your algorithm is to use bitwise operators -- instead of having to divide by powers of two explicitly with `Math.pow`, you can use bitwise operators to test if bits are on or off, and then print out 1's and 0's accordingly. For example:

```
public static void toBinary(int n) {
   int mask = 1, nn = n;
   while(nn != 0) {
      mask << 1;
      nn /= 2;
   }
   mask >>= 1;

   while(mask != 0) {
      System.out.print( (mask & n) ? "1" : "0" );
      mask >>= 1;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Also, your `userNum = userNum` is redundant in the `for` loop. Just use a null statement (`;`) in the assignment part of the loop instead. So:

`for(; (Math.pow(2, count) <= userNum); count++) {`